# How can I render uneditable fields in django modelform factory

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to render model forms for my queryset which is just a model.objects.all(), however I dont want all fields to be editable but I still want the uneditable ones to appear as normal text. How can I do this? this is what I understand so far:

So the way you use modelformsetfactory according to the doc is like this :
Views:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from myapp.models import Author

def manage_authors(request):
   AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Author, fields=('name', 'title'))
   if request.method == "POST":
       formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                  queryset=Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='O'))
       if formset.is_valid():
          formset.save()

       else:
        formset = AuthorFormSet(queryset=Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='O'))
return render_to_response("manage_authors.html", {
    "formset": formset,
})
```

Templates:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {% for form in formset %}
         {{ form }}
      {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

And I also get that you can render individual fields, what I'd liek to know is how to render the fields that you do not want to be part of the form but still displayed.

For example:

```
  Name(not editable form field)  Team(not editable)  School(editable form field)  Gender(editable)  Phone#(not editable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually very simple, where you would add {{form}}, simply add {{form.value}} and that gives me exactly what I was looking for. So if you did:

```
  {% for x in formset %}

   #in here would be
    {{x.fieldname.value}} #simple

  {% endfor %}
```